How can consciousness arise from material substance?
How can consciousness arise from material substance? And how can matter produce subjective experience?


If you start from "cogito ergo sum" then the question is how can material substance arise from consciousness.

It’s pretty straightforward, should all be on Wikipedia.

Reading a few books on neuroscience might be a good starting point if you want to know that. Seems a bit too broad for a Q&A, and not so much about philosophy (philosophy of mind is deep in philosophy, but the material understanding of it is science, instead). And I don't know what sort of mechanical wizardry is going on in your image, but there is plenty of detailed imagery available of how the brain works at varying levels of detail, from which parts of the brain does what, to how neurons function.

This question is similar to: How can inanimate matter provide subjective experiences. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@NotThatGuy Do you actually have any neuroscience citations which claim to have solved the hard problem of consciousness?  Please post them.  The links I find are far less positive than you imply:  https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/52710/29339 https://nautil.us/an-existential-crisis-in-neuroscience-237680/ https://www.madinamerica.com/2022/09/influential-neuroscientist-failure/

@Dcleve I'd suggest rereading my comment, because that's not what I said in any way, shape or form. Given our less-than-amicable past interactions, I'll just leave it at that.

Truth  is not beauty.
Knowledge is not power.


Looking for truth to find beauty would be ... a category error (kind of). The benefit of truth is its usefulness. But plenty of scientists find plenty of beauty in the things they study (including in how the brain works). Knowledge is not power, but it is a catalyst to power. It enables you to more reliably realise your wishes, because you can more accurately predict the outcomes of your actions, including preparing for things that might happen to you.

@NotThatGuy >Looking for beauty in truth is ... a category error. === Depends what you think of beautiful. === Knowledge enables you to more reliably realise your wishes, because you can more accurately predict the outcomes of your actions. === That's what they tell kids. It shooo' 'nuff ain't worked out for me. Your mileage may vary.

If you're hungry, useful knowledge would be that eating food would satisfy your hunger, and that certain food are edible and others aren't. For that, it probably wouldn't be too useful to know the chemical makeup of a distant star. Most people accept that relevant knowledge facilitates the fulfilment of one's wishes and the accurate prediction of outcomes in their daily life. But sometimes that idea gets muddled on its way to larger-scale thinking and more difficult problems. And certainly, not all knowledge is fun to learn, but it sure is useful to have knowledge of when your house is on fire

@NotThatGuy >If you're hungry, it probably wouldn't be too useful to know the chemical makeup of a distant star. === Yeah, in a larger sense, that's always been my problem.
